# Is it correct and natural to say "my finger tips are stinging with cold"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, collocations

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to say "my hands are stinging with cold"? For example:

> I've been outside for too long and now **my finger tips are stinging with cold**.

If doesn't sound good what would be a more natural way to say that you feel this stinging pain caused by the cold?

Comment: _Tingling_ is more idiomatic, but _stinging_ doesn't sound obviously wrong.

Comment: *Stinging* sounds good and sounds a lot more painful than *tingling*! You can also use *numb*, although that's when you're so cold you can't feel anything anymore. We'd normally say *fingertips* though

Comment: Unless you specifically want to draw attention to your fingertips, I would be more likely to talk about _my fingers_ or _my hands_.   _Stinging with cold_ works, or more colloquially _my hands are freezing_ although that does not necessarily imply pain.